# Mysql join should return all from table A not in table B AND where clause for table B

Tags: mysql

I hope this makes sense, I find a lot of questions like this, however not sure how to word it best for my specific scenario.

I have table A, is a user table, table B is a filter table of different types of filters:

```
table A - User
    id, name, email

table B - Filters
    id, filter_type, user_id
```

So a user can have any number of filter types - or NONE at all.

I need a join query that gets all the users that are NOT being filtered for a requested type, even if they don't exist in table B.

So if i have user data:

```
1, John, john@gmail.com
2, Mike, mike@gmail.com
3, Fred, fred@gmail.com
```

With filters set for only John:

```
id | type | user_id
----------------
1, type1, 1
2, type2, 1
```

Lets say we have filter types: type1, type2, type3, and I need ALL user's except those that have a filter for type1, I should still get back john: type2 and type3, as well as all for Mike and Fred.

Hope that makes sense

I start with the following:

```
select u.id, u.name, f.type from users u
left join filters f on f.user_id = u.id
where f.type != 'type1'
```

This is only returning John type2 and type3 .... but not including Mike and Fred.
I've also tried different join types, but then i'm unclear on the where clause, any tips appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing with your current attempt, you want an anti-join here, so you need another criterion in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN filters f
    ON f.user_id = u.id AND f.type = 'type1'
WHERE
    f.user_id IS NULL;
```

However, I feel that phrasing your query using exists logic is more sensible:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM filters f
                  WHERE f.user_id = u.id AND f.type = 'type1');
```

Comment: perfect - i think for the structure i'm using, first answer is great, thanks will mark as soon as i can

Comment: @yoyoma The "trick" in the first query (which is actually easy to botch), is that the filter restriction goes into the `ON` clause of the join.  This means that non matching users will have `NULL` "holes" for all fields from the `filters` table.  Then, we keep only users which did _not_ match to the `type1` filter.